# How can I show fancybox on click of a button (Example)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, fancybox, code-behind

I have a web application, and the requirements need to show jquery lightbox as a confirmation message including some information.

After some research I found fancybox [FancyBox Jquery Light box](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful)

I followed this step by step till I could show the required confirmation message in a fancy box, which is triggered by `<a href="#popup" class="fancybox">Open</a>`

I need to trigger or show the fancy box from code behind of an asp:button

I've searched a lot and all results that I got when applied did not work.

Can any one please show me a sample about triggering fancybox from code behind of asp button in c# and attach it here?

that is a sample of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery   /1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.0" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.0"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    afterLoad: function () {
        this.content = this.content.html();
    }
});
</script>


<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <a href="#test" class="fancybox">Open</a>

    <div id="test" style="display:none;width:300px;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="Hello" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Press Here" />            
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

This code is work correctly and show the fancybox after click on open link
all my need is to show the fancybox after click on asp:button

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not an expert ASP developer here, but once the element gets rendered so the page, you're able to then reference it as an HTML element within the `$(document).ready` function provided by jQuery, where we can then invoke `$('.fancybox').fancybox()`

Comment: for sorry i try it and not work thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

To call javascript from Code Behind, you can do something like this in your button click event handler:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "fancyBoxScript", "[JAVASCRIPT TO INVOKE FANCYBOX]", true);
```

This javascript will be sent to the page and executed after the post-back is finished.

Edit: You can find more information here about invoking FancyBox through javascript.  It basically requires you to simulate a click on a hidden button: http://thingsilearned.com/2010/01/27/dynamically-calling-fancybox-from-javascript/

Comment: i added a sample code of what i do, please see the code you can understand my problem from code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a script tag for JQuery in your < head > like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also in the head, reference the script file themselves, along with the stylesheet like this (assuming you've copied the files to therootofyourwebsite/fancybox/source):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.0" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.0"></script>
```

Then, at the bottom of your < body > (but still inside body) make sure you wire up fancybox,  something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i added a sample code of what i do, please see the code you can understand my problem from code

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to launch fancybox from a `html` button like :

```
<button id="newOpen" type="button">open fancybox from button</button>
```

....what it matters here is the rendered `html` button, via `asp` or any other programming language. Also notice that this `button` **is not** part of the form (opened in fancybox)

If the above is correct, since you already have the code to launch fancybox from the `open` link, then just add this piece of jQuery code :

```
$("#newOpen").bind("click", function(){
 $(".fancybox").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: yes you understand correctly but with asp button 
but i try it now not work ..... thanks for your response